# Add post build shell script to Groovy job executioner

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a script that looks like this:

cronjobs.groovy :

```
job('MYJOB') {

  triggers {
    cron('H * ** *')
  }

  steps {
    shell('some shell script')
    shell('some othre shell')
  }
}
```

I want to add another shell to run here on failure of MYJOB execution. Is it possible?
Or must I implement a pipeline? Can I implement this in this manner? And do I need any plugin for that?

```
job('MYJOB') {

  triggers {
    cron('H * ** *')
  }

  steps {
    shell('some shell script')
    shell('some other shell script')
  }

  post {
    failure {
      shell('some shell script')
      shell('some more shell script')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to job dsl [docs](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job), job have post-build action using publishers directive, but you can't specify failure condition and also you can't execute shell commands directly though you can invoke a [groovy script](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-publishers-groovyPostBuild).

So it's better to go for a pipeline instead

Comment: Thanks. But won't this work?
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext.postBuildScripts